# Is there a way to preview pdf/image files in the browser?

Tags: python, odoo

To open the files uploaded though the fields.binary, I have to download the file then open it from my computer. However the business requirement says that the documents( pdf and images only ) should be previewed from the browser.

One approach is to get the full url path of the fields.binary resource and then embed a pdf or image viewer. BUT I couldn't find a way to get the full path url of the resource( image, pdf )

Is there a way to preview pdf/image files in the browser?

Comment: you can see a nice technique used in Odoo financial report module V11 you can see the document in HTML or PDF or excel and it's not that hard to understand the Idea

Answer (score 0):

Just directly give your imagefile name.

```
<a href="filename.png"><img src="filename.png" title="Image" alt="Image"></a>
```